# Accessing Ajax data from another Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to access first ajax data to add a new value (option2). I can access first ajax data with this.data in beforesend function, but I cannot use "this" in another ajax because it refers to it. So, how to access first ajax data?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controller.php",
    data: {
        'option1': 1
        //option2 needs to be accessible here

    },
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        var firstAjax = this;

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "controller.php",
            data: {
                getNewOption: 1
            },
            success: function (res) {
                firstAjax.data += '&' + $.param({
                    option2: res
                });
            }
        });

    },
    success: function (msg) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: Is `firstAjax.data` not what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried, but I cannot pass it.

Comment: What are you looking to access, and when, exactly ?

Comment: After success beforesend function, I would like to attach "res" data to "option2" and pass it into first ajax data

Comment: Your ajax calls are backwards.  You need the result of ajax-2 to be part of the parameters for ajax-1.  Rewrite this so that ajax-1 is called in the `success` portion of ajax-2.

Comment: I know I can achieve it like this, but this is not an option.

Comment: Do me a favor and add `console.log("Success ajax-1")` in the success for ajax-1 and `console.log("Success ajax-2")` in the success for ajax-2.  Tell me what shows up on the console.

Comment: Of course, the console will show both messages, but what I need are the parameters that need to be sent. In this case: option1, and dynamically loaded option2 which needs to be added to first ajax data.

Comment: The point is actually the order they show in.  The problem is that your `beforeSend` ends before the ajax-2 completes.  This means that ajax-1 starts before ajax-2 finishes, which is why you can't get the info you need.  You are trying to chain ajax calls and you can't do that in a `beforeSend` the way you have it.  The correct way is to put the second one in the `success` of the first.

Comment: please take a look at my edit, this is awkward, I just saw nurdyguy's last comment

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need `res` to be part of the data used in the first ajax call, since `data` is an object try assigning res to `.option2`

let me know

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "controller.php",
data: {
    'option1': 1
    //option2 needs to be accessible here

},
beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
    var firstAjax = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "controller.php",
        data: {
            getNewOption: 1
        },
        success: function (res) {
            firstAjax.data.option2 = res
        }
    });

},
success: function (msg) {
    //...
}
});
```

**EDIT**

As [nurdyguy accurately pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909223/accessing-ajax-data-from-another-ajax/49909489#comment86835638_49909489), the second ajax call is indeed running before the first's data is submitted to the server BUT, the second's result, being asynchronous and all, is NOT returning before the first's data is sent, hence the first's data is not *leaving* with `option2` set. Consider this workaround changing the order of the ajax calls:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "controller2.php",
    data: {
        getNewOption: 1
    },
    success: function (res) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "controller1.php",
            data: {
                'option1': 1
                'option2': res
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                //...
            }
        });
    },
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR){}
});
```

would this be feasible?

Comment: The reason this won't work is because `beforeSend` function will actually complete before the ajax finishes, which is why OP is having his problem.  The only way this could work is if the inner ajax is done as synchronous which is a really really bad idea.